# How to execute a function in JavaScript/typescript whose definition is stored in string

Tags: javascript, typescript, string, window, eval

How can i call a function whose definition is stored in string? e.g

```
var dynamicFun = `function Hello(person) {   return 'Hello' + person; }`
```

here the **dynamicFun** variable can hold any function definition dynamically e.g it can be

```
var dynamicFun = `function Sum(num) {   return num + num; }`
```

At compile time I would be not aware which function definition is assigned to **dynamicFun** variable. It is getting assigned at runtime so How can I call the above functions using **dynamicFun** variable with params (without knowing the actual function name or definition) in javascript/typescript.

Comment: @GrafiCode Yes it has my answer.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the Eval Global Function in JS.

By the way, this isn't considered great practice for security reasons. I'm curious as to why you might be looking to do this as there might be a better solution.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

```
console.log(eval('2 + 2'));
console.log(eval('"Hello" + " " + "World"'));
```

I hope this answers your question!